# Gazebo menu save is always grayed out..why is this?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo menu save is always grayed out. The Save As menu is not. Why is this. I tried permissions on the directory and file but still does not allow save.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4204/gazebo-menu-save-is-always-grayed-out..why-is-this?/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/449/rnunziata/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 107 on 2013-08-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I believe this is normal ... it will only let you save a world that you do a saveAs on first. You can also using SaveAs locate and replace the current world in your files. The launch world file could have been a composite or from a non local source.

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/449/rnunziata/) with karma: 107 on 2013-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1